# I'm having trouble with my code String and int

Tags: java

I can't really explain what I'm trying to do. But I guess the code will give the intention.

I'm having trouble, **I'm trying to print out `String dasipirktiPakuociu`, but it requires `int`.**

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dasipirktiPakuociu = skaiciuokle(300);
        parodykArReikiaDarPirkti("Vištienos",300, dasipirktiPakuociu);

        dasipirktiPakuociu = skaiciuokle(151);
        parodykArReikiaDarPirkti("Kalakutienos",151, dasipirktiPakuociu);

        dasipirktiPakuociu = skaiciuokle(120);
        parodykArReikiaDarPirkti("Vištienos",120, dasipirktiPakuociu);

        dasipirktiPakuociu = skaiciuokle(-1);
        parodykArReikiaDarPirkti("Kalakutienos",-1, dasipirktiPakuociu);
    }

    public static void parodykArReikiaDarPirkti(String maistoRusys,int svorisEsamas, int kiekis) {
        System.out.println(maistoRusys + " yra " + svorisEsamas + " g., reikės dapirkti " + kiekis + " pakuotę" );
    }

    public static String skaiciuokle (int svorisEsamas) {
        if(svorisEsamas >= 300) {
            return "as";
        } else if (300 > svorisEsamas && svorisEsamas >= 150) {
            return "s";
        } else if (150 > svorisEsamas && svorisEsamas >= 0) {
            return "d";
        } else if (svorisEsamas < 0) {
            return "a";
        }
        return "Empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: *I can't really explain what I'm trying to do.* - And we can't really understand what you're trying to do

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) Meaningful method and attribute names are only meaningful if the reader understands the language the are written in! Given English is the default language of SO, please translate method, attribute & class names into English as best you're able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing this

```
int dasipirktiPakuociu = skaiciuokle(300);
```

you are assigning the return value of the method, a `String`, to an `int`. An `int` can only hold integer numbers – what do you expect to happen when you assign it something like `"as"`?

Either change the return value of your method to `int` or change your variable to `String`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but in your `skaiciuokle` function, use a variable instead of returning a string, put an else at the end, and then return the variable. So it should look like this:

```
  public static String skaiciuokle (int svorisEsamas) {
String s = "";
if(svorisEsamas >= 300) {
    s = "as";
} else if (300 > svorisEsamas && svorisEsamas >= 150) {
    s = "s";
} else if (150 > svorisEsamas && svorisEsamas >= 0) {
    s = "d";
} else if (svorisEsamas < 0) {
    s = "a";
} else {
s = "Empty";
}
return s;
}
```